# Accessing Geospatial anchors made in the Geospatial Creator

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I played around with the Geospatial Creator for Unity. I placed an object and run/built the sample app on my phone. No issues there.
But how can I access these anchors outside that demo app? Surely that can't be the only usage as people would need to use these anchors in custom apps.
I thought I that by creating and adding the anchors there I could access them, based on my API Key, from a custom app, built in Android Studio.

Is that possible at all?
Or is the Unity Creator only meant to be used to create pre-packaged experiences?
Or are we supposed to use the Geospatial creator to place the anchors visually, but then extract the lat/long/rotation/altitude from the editor and then hardcode it separately in a custom app?